# Simplfy type casting in rust

Tags: optimization, rust, casting

```
impl Solution {
      pub fn find_max_average(nums: Vec<i32>, k: i32) -> f64 {
          let mut curr:i32=0;
          let mut ans:f64;
          for i in 0..k {
             curr += nums[i as usize]; 
          }   
          ans=curr as f64/k as f64;
              
          for i in k..nums.len() as i32 {
              curr += nums[i as usize] - nums[(i-k) as usize];
              ans = ans.max(curr as f64/k as f64);
          }   
          return ans 
      }   
  }
```

This code works, it's for a leetcode problem (calculate max average of a subarray). However, being a beginner in rust, it took me quite a while to get this to compile - specifically, a lot of type casts were needed. The `fn` signature was given.

Can this be improved? Does rust suggests the tradeoff of less readability (in my opinion, the above is not so readable) of the the code against failproof type safety? Or is this only subjective, and as the code gets improved, the supposed tradeoff goes away?

Comment: `cargo fmt` is a thing... please run it before posting.

Comment: As for your actual question, the tradeoff is not precisely between readability and type safety it is between *exposing the details of the implementation to give you the programmer more control* (Rust, C++) and *glossing over the details to present a facade of simplicity* (JS, Python). I glanced at your profile. In the languages you are used to you essentially never have to worry about whether you're on a 32, 64, whatever-bit architecture to calculate memory address offsets. Rust does not hide this. I do wish though there were better options for dividing integers, for that one I got nuthin.

Comment: Awesome explanation @JaredSmith, makes a lot of sense. And yes, will use fmt in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I second @cadolphs recommendation to cast your types at the beginning of the function to avoid needing to cast later, although would recommend to use `.into()` (or `.try_into()` as applicable) instead of `as` like so:

```
let n: usize = k.try_into().unwrap();
```

The reasoning is that the behavior of `as` casting often isn't the desired behavior in the corner cases.

For example, `let n = k as usize` would give a bad result if `k` (an `i32`) happens to be negative, it would sign-extend the value and then interpret it as positive, resulting in a huge `n`. In contrast, `.try_into()` would check to make sure `k` could be properly converted to a `usize`, returning an `Err` if it could not be converted.

In general, by default you probably want to use `.into()` (or `.try_into()`) for casting, unless you fully understand [the behavior of `as` casting](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html?highlight=semantics#semantics) (and you actually desire that behavior).

Answer (score 2):

A few things to make your life easier.

First, finding the max average of a sequence of length `k` is exactly the same task as finding the max sum of a sequence of length `k`, so you can skip dividing by `k` until the very end.

And then you can introduce variables of the right type to help you. Like, add

```rust
let n = k as usize
```

because then when you do `for i in 0..n` you won't have to cast the `i` to `usize`.

Then get rid of everywhere you divide by `k` but just at the very end do

```rust
ans as f64 / k as f64
```